# Datadog - hiding applicationId and clientToken

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datadog

I have angular application and I integrate it with datadog application in order to use Session and Replay (RUM). Is there a way to hide the applicationId and clientToken, because in this current way, anyone who opens the inspect/network in the browser can access this sensitive information and connect to my datadog application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application id and client token are not sensitive data, they are designed to be used in client-side code, much like other tokens in other tools that collect browser data such as Google Analytics. You could obfuscate them by [proxying your requests](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/guide/proxy-rum-data/?tab=npm) but there's not much to be gained by doing so.